# Values replacing themselves in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push input value into an array based on input fields. But the problem I'm facing here is that the last input field will replace all the objects in my array like this:

```
[
   {
      "label":"4",
      "type":"",
      "process":"",
      "name":"5",
      "col":"6"
   },
   {
      "label":"4",
      "type":"",
      "process":"",
      "name":"5",
      "col":"6"
   }
]
```

What I'm expecting it to return is the value of each input in each field separately. This means that instead of seeing the object above, it should be label: 1, name: 2, col: 3 etc etc in the correct order. I'm not sure what I'm missing here because my code makes sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

```js
 $(document).ready(() => {
  $('.add-field').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    generateField();
  });

  $('.form-maker').submit(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const temp = {},
      payload = [];

    $('.dynamic-group').each((i, group) => {
      $(group)
        .find('input, select')
        .each((ii, field) => {
          temp[field.name] = field.value;
        });

      payload.push(temp);
    });

    console.log(payload);
  });

  const generateField = () => {
    $('.dynamic-fields').append(
      `
    <div class="form-inline dynamic-group">
      <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">Input Label</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Label" name="label">
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">Input Type</div>
        </div>
        <select name="type" name="type">
          <option value="">Something in here</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">Process</div>
        </div>
        <select name="process" name="process">
          <option value="">Something in here</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">Input Name</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Name" name="name">
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">DB. Col Name</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DB. Col Name" name="col">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr />
    
    `
    );
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic-fields"></div>

<button class="add-field">
    Add Field
</button>

<button type="submit">
    Make Form
</button>
```

Comment: Move `const temp = {}` inside `$('.dynamic-group').each((i, group) => {...}` to make new object for each group instead of using the same object because in your case, all objects pushed in the `payload` array refer to the same single object and they reflect/show the same value.

Comment: That's also a good point I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're referencing the same object every time, so the last thing to get updated wins. You'd want a copy of the object pushed into the array:

```
$('.dynamic-group').each((i, group) => {
      $(group)
        .find('input, select')
        .each((ii, field) => {
          temp[field.name] = field.value;
        });

      payload.push($.extend(true,{},temp));
    });
```

There are a number of ways to make object copies - in this case I'm using JQuery's extend method to make a true copy of the object, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

```
$.extend(true,{},temp)
```

Comment: `$.extend` was the answer. Didn't know that existed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `temp` variable must be placed within the inner loop of each group:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".add-field").click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    generateField();
  });

  $(".form-maker").click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const payload = [];

    $(".dynamic-group").each((i, group) => {
    
      const temp = {};

      $(group)
        .find("input, select")
        .each((ii, field) => {
          temp[field.name] = field.value;
        });

      payload.push(temp);
    });

    console.log(payload);
  });

  const generateField = () => {
    $(".dynamic-fields").append(
      `
   <div class="form-inline dynamic-group">
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">Input Label</div>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Label" name="label">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">Input Type</div>
     </div>
     <select name="type" name="type">
      <option value="">Something in here</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">Process</div>
     </div>
     <select name="process" name="process">
      <option value="">Something in here</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">Input Name</div>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Name" name="name">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">DB. Col Name</div>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DB. Col Name" name="col">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <hr />
   
   `
    );
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic-fields"></div>

<button class="add-field">
    Add Field
</button>

<button class="form-maker" type="submit">
    Make Form
</button>
```